# Adding Equal Width Multiplier to .xib component with no super view?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

To clear this question up a bit, I need to address following aspects

1. I am following this article to create reusable button component, which in its essence is just an image view with label and user actions enabled it is based on [.xib and cocoa class files](https://medium.com/@brianclouser/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960)
2. I am also following this [auto layout practice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vegamwo6SvU) to size some of my elements based on screen widths

**The issue**

I want my button component to be 0.4 equal width of the screen, the issue is that it doesn't have a super view I can size against i.e. it only has one when I include it into certain view controllers. Because of this option "Equal Width" in auto layout is disabled to me. As a work around, I can size it once I included into some view, but this harms reusability of component, I'd rather it occupy 0.4 equal width of its super view by default.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a UIView [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622433-didmovetosuperview) `didMoveToSuperview()` to get the superview. It gets called whenever the superview changes.
For example:

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    guard let currentSuperview = self.superview else { return }
}
```

Then you can set the width constraint programmatically since you have a superview to relate to.